# Not receiving e-email notification when creating new tasks in a custom sequential workflow

Tags: development, workflow, visual-studio, email, tasks

I am setting the AssignedTo and SendEmailNotification properties for the SPWorkflowTaskProperties object, the task gets created and assigned correctly but no email is received.

How can I check if this email is not getting sent or if it is getting sent but somehow blocked by the mail server?

Note that all other emails seem to be working correctly.

Thanks

Comment: are you sending emails to a group?

Comment: No, it's a single user

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I randomly came across the solution on this [post](http://chamindasomathilaka.wordpress.com/2011/09/28/getting-sp-custom-workflow-taskproperties-sendemailnotification-to-send-emails/).

The problem was the E-Mail Notification option in the Advanced Task List Settings. This needs to be set to true and on a custom list this can be done by setting the attribute EmailAssignTo to true on the list definition.

```
<List xmlns:ows="Microsoft SharePoint" EmailAssignTo="TRUE">

</List>
```

I don't think this option is documented on MSDN. 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms415091.aspx

Comment: Hmm, I'm wondering why this answer was marked and not mine.

Comment: I had solved my problem before you answered, just couldn't post my solution due to time limit. But I wouldn't have been able to solve it with your answer anyway since it doesn't tell me how to set that option in a custom list. More than happy to mark your's as an answer if you want.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are not using an email activity  in wf, did you checked the option 'Send e-mail when ownership is assigned?' in the associated Tasks list is set to yes ?

Answer (score 0):

Can you try sending the mail using [System.Net.Mail](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.smtpclient.aspx) ? Here you have a property called [DeliveryNotificationOptions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.deliverynotificationoptions.aspx) which could bring you delivery notification status whatever happens.